# Can't apply class to menu item

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with this code below:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location;
  var element = $('#nav1  li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
  }).parent().addClass('navigation__active');
  if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('navigation__active').parent().parent('li').addClass('navigation__active')
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="nav1" class="navigation">
<li class="navigation__active"><a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> 
   Home</a></li>

 <li class="navigation__sub">
    <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-week"></i> About</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
  <li class="navigation__active"><a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> 
    Contact</a></li>
 <ul>
```

For now I can select About>History,Team, Projects for example and that's works, fine but I when i click Home or Contact - navigation__active class is not applied.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Note: if you're going to write javascript, I strongly recommend you use `===` instead of `==`.  It'll save you loads of headaches later.

Comment: Second note: Formatting matters. Due to your formatting (prior to the kind edit from @epascarello), it was difficult to understand what your JS was actually doing.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664530/add-active-class-to-navigation-items

Comment: "when i click Home or Contact - navigation__active class is not applied" - There is nothing in your code listening for a click event. Are you missing something..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add active class to navigation items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664530/add-active-class-to-navigation-items)

Comment: It does not work when the top level li does not have an li like your code is looking for.

Comment: @Zim, your comment reminds me of [this](https://cdn.dopl3r.com/memes_files/dedication-at-its-finest-dec-14-2013-at-953-pm-memelordmadmax-hey-thanks-for-accept-mai-request-i-laik-ube-my-gurlfrand-im-14-ohh-dec-14-2017-at-958-pm-hey-so-u-18-now-ye2s6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to apply a class to the current selected menu item based on the url in the address bar.  I would build this as a single page app so you can track menu state and then update the page content based on the selected menu item instead of the approach you took.

If you want to do it the way you are here, this code is probably closer to what you're looking for than what you have.  I had to hard-code a few things, but I think you'll get the idea about what you're doing wrong in the JS at least.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = {href: "https://stacksnippets.net/test"};
  var element = $('#nav1  li a').filter(function(index, el) {
    return url.href === el.href;
  });
  
  var selectedElem = $(element[0]);
  
  if (selectedElem.parent().is('li')) {
    selectedElem.parent('li').addClass('navigation__active')
    var paretnMenuItem = selectedElem.parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li');
    paretnMenuItem.children('a').addClass('navigation__active')
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation__active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav1" class="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Home</a>
  </li>

  <li class="navigation__sub">
    <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-week"></i> About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="test">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Contact</a>
  </li>
 <ul>
```